# decompose a linear transform into sum of some other linear transform

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

Suppose I have a linear transformation $T: V\longrightarrow V$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Let $A$ be the matrix representation of $T$ under the basis $\beta$ of $V$.

Are there linear transformations $T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4, \dots$ such that $T= \sum_i T_i$? Or is there is a way to approach that goal?

Also, will it be true that $A$ is the sum of the matrix representation of each of $T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4, \dots$ under basis $\beta$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course there are. You can have $T_1=T$, $T_i=0$ for $i\geq 2$. or $T_1=T$ and $T_{2k}=-T_{2k+1}$ for $k\geq 1$ (with an odd number of $T_i$'s). Without additional context it's hard to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, for example $T=\frac{T+T}{2}$. You probably want the $T_i$ to be indecomposable in a certain sense.

Comment: The primary decomposition theorem gives a direct sum decomposition $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k V_i$ in $T$-invariant subspaces, and if $T_i = T\big|_{V_i}$, then $T = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k T_i$. Extending each $T_i$ by zero you get $T = \sum_{i=1}^k T_i$.

Comment: What is that direct sum of linear transform mean? Also, what's extending linear transform by zero mean?